# ionic 2: marge details with same values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have array of objects that i get from my database response.
each object has name of course, name lecture, class,hours,day.
in my data base it's relationship of one to many -> means each lecture has many lessons so i have table of lectures and table of times.

the times table has foreign_key of the lecture_id it means
lectures table: lecture_id(primary_key) +more attributes.
times table:id_lecture(foreign_key),id_time(primary_key) +more attributes.
i did a query

> "SELECT * from lectures,Times where id_lecture=lecture_id";

it works fine and give me the results i want.
the problem is that each lecture has some lessons and i want to display these lessons in same ion-item and marge it to one object.
in other words i want to do like that.
[image]

that's my code to get the data

```
  this.coursesData.LoadLectures()
        .subscribe(LectureList=> {
           console.log("getLec1");
          LectureList.forEach(lecture=>{
            console.log(lecture);
          var newLecture={
                name:lecture.name,
                email:lecture.email,
                phone:lecture.phone ,
                lesson_type:lecture.lesson_type ,
                detailsHours:{'start_time':lecture.start_time,'end_time':lecture.end_time,'class':lecture.class, 'day':lecture.day},
                details:lecture.details,
                course_name:lecture.course_name
          }
            this.coursesA.push(newLecture);
            this.coursesNames.push(lecture.course_name);
            this.LecturesNames.push(lecture.name);
          });
          //this.courseSelect=this.coursesNames[0];
          this.coursesAD=this.coursesA;
          this.coursesNames = this.coursesNames.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
                  return index == self.indexOf(elem);
              })
             // console.log("co"+this.coursesA);


               this.loader.dismiss();
               //console.log(this.LecturesNames);
        // return this.coursesA;

        },err=>{
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

as you can see the newLecture contains

```
 var newLecture={
                name:lecture.name,
                email:lecture.email,
                phone:lecture.phone ,
                lesson_type:lecture.lesson_type ,
                detailsHours:{'start_time':lecture.start_time,'end_time':lecture.end_time,'class':lecture.class, 'day':lecture.day},
                details:lecture.details,
                course_name:lecture.course_name
          }
```

but there are many with some lessons so if i do this way it's problem because it will duplicate the names.

i tried this way but it shows me error

```
 public Lectures(){
  console.log("getLec");
  this.courseSelect='';
  this.coursesNames=[];
  this.LecturesNames=[];
  this.coursesA=[];

 this.coursesData.LoadLectures()
    .subscribe(LectureList=> {
       console.log("getLec1");
      LectureList.forEach(lecture=>{
        console.log(lecture);
      var newLecture={
            id:lecture.id_lecture,
            name:lecture.name,
            email:lecture.email,
            phone:lecture.phone ,
            lesson_type:lecture.lesson_type ,
            detailsHours:{'start_time':lecture.start_time,'end_time':lecture.end_time,'class':lecture.class, 'day':lecture.day},
            details:lecture.details,
            course_name:lecture.course_name
      }
        console.log("de"+newLecture.detailsHours.start_time);
        if(!newLecture.id){
          this.coursesA[newLecture.id]=newLecture;
       // this.coursesNames.push(lecture.course_name);
        //this.LecturesNames.push(lecture.name);
        }
        else{
          this.coursesA[newLecture.id].push(newLecture);
        }

      });
      this.coursesAD=this.coursesA;

      //this.courseSelect=this.coursesNames[0];

      console.log(this.coursesA);
      /*this.coursesNames = this.coursesNames.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
              return index == self.indexOf(elem);
          })
           */

         // console.log("co"+this.coursesA);

           this.loader.dismiss();
           console.log("lets"+this.LecturesNames);
    // return this.coursesA;


    },err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
```

}

i got this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

someone has any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use subarrays to group you courses by name (or course_name). Instead of pushing `newLecture` inside `courseA`, you could push it inside `courseA[newLecture.name]`.

Thus, you will have something like:

```
{
    "JAVA Course": [
      { lecture1 },
      { lecture2 }
    }],
    "JS Course": [
      { lecture3 },
      { lecture4 }
    }]
}
```

Then, in your template you could do:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">
    <p>{{key}}</p> <!-- example: JAVA Course -->
    <div ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in value">
        {{subvalue}} <!-- example: lecture hours -->
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do but i tried to do couseA[newLecture.name].push(newLecture) and it's not working. it shows error "EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: in addition there are no ng-repeat in angular2

Comment: You need to init the subarray before pushing an object into it `if(!courseA[newLecture.name]) courseA[newLecture.name] = [ ]`. I didn't catch you were on ionic2, but that's pretty the same way to do it with `ngFor`

Comment: this way it will put the the new data instead the one it was. it didn't push this way.

Comment: No it won't. It will create an array if it does not exist. Then, you will be able to push your lecture inside and you won't have the "EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Your code should look like: `if(!courseA[newLecture.name]) { courseA[newLecture.name] = [ ] } courseA[newLecture.name].push(newLecture)`

Comment: this way i get error "typeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". i edit the post with changes you said me to do

Comment: I uploaded to github you can are in src/pages/course-page.ts and providers/course-data.ts